# Docker and EF Core: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: docker, sql-server-2017, docker-for-windows, ef-core-2.1

I try to connect to the host's SQL Server Instance (`SQL 2017` on `Windows 10`) from a Docker container (running a .NET Core app with EF Core).

The SQL Server is configured to listen on the default port `1433` (no dynamic ports are used) and to allow remote connections (`TCP/IP`). I also set up an inbound rule for the firewall and the given port (I also tried with firewall off). I can connect to the database and run SQL queries with the `sqlcmd` command line tool running in a Docker container.

This is the connection string I'm using:

`Server=tcp:host.docker.internal,1433;Database=AuthIdentity;Trusted_Connection=False;User Id=sa;Password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;`

When I run my container I get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it.)

When I turn off my firewall (even if there is a firewall rule for the SQL port) I'll end up getting:

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond.)

When I start the same program as IIS application (without any other changes) it's running perfectly fine and it's connecting as expected.

The error occurs when the program executes the first SQL operations (in this case it's the database migration - this is within the program startup)

```
serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
```

---

**EDIT**: A simpler setup in another API project (both will raise the same errors as described above):

```
    [HttpGet("setup")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Setup()
    {
        try
        {
            this._context.Database.Migrate();
            return Ok("success");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(e);
        }

    }

    [HttpGet("get")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public List<ApplicationUser> Get()
    {
        return this._context.Users.ToList();
    }
```

---

**EDIT 2**: As suggested from @Mohsin Mehmood I run a test with the `NAT` address (from `ipconfig /all`) and I can successfully connect with the given IP (`172.28.112.1`) to the SQL server. I also checked what I receive when running `docker run --rm -i microsoft/nanoserver:1709 ping host.docker.internal` and it gets me `62.138.239.45` as the address.

Never the less I would appreciate a solution which is not using a "hard-coded" IP address but a DNS like `host.docker.internal`. I'm also not sure why both IP addresses are different (`172.28.112.1` vs. `62.138.239.45`) and why the container can't get the correct address from the DNS.

---

What are the things I'm missing? How can this problem be solved? I already searched Google and SO without any working answer.

Comment: Login into running container and see if you can resolve that name mentioned from command prompt

Comment: I can connect to the database and run SQL queries with the `sqlcmd` command line tool running in a Docker container

Comment: By using the same hostname as in your question `tcp:host.docker.internal,1433`?

Comment: By using the command line syntax `sqlcmd -S host.docker.internal -U sa -P xxxx`. It's a distinct SQL client running in a docker container.

Comment: I'm not sure what `Service Migration` is. I suggest create simple ASP.NET page with only connectivity check to DB to isolate application issue from container issue

Comment: I tested with an "as simple as possible setup" now, but the error still remains the same. Anytime I try to run an `EF operation` there is a connection problem to the host's SQL server.

Comment: @Alex, as per my understanding SQL Server is hosted outside docker(on windows 10) so have you tried using sql server host IP address in connectionstring instead of  `host.docker.internal`?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood: Yes, your understanding is correct. I'm not sure about the host IP address and I'm quite sure it will change on the different deploy systems (Dev, Staging, Prod). In my opinion, it would be best if I could use a DNS (just like `host.docker.internal`) and rely on this. Furthermore, it's working as expected with the `sqlcmd` so it's most likely not a problem of the host's connectivity.

Comment: @Alex, Just a suggestion that if you try connecting using IP address then it will be confirmed that issue is related to connectivity using DNS.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood: You are right ... When I test with the `nat` IP address (in this case `172.28.112.1`) it can successfully connect to the SQL server *sigh*. But why is it not possible to use the DNS as the Docker docs suggest? And also, why is it possible to use the DNS from the `sqlcmd` without any problems?

Comment: Additionally, i can run `docker run --rm -i microsoft/nanoserver:1709 ping host.docker.internal` successful and it resolves an IP address but it's different from the `nat` address (`62.138.239.45`)

Comment: @Alex Check this https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1976. Its still  an open issue

Comment: @MohsinMehmood: When you make your comments an answer I can accept it and award you the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to try Windows 10 host server IP address instead of domain `host.docker.internal` to confirm that issue is related to DNS resolution. Also, I found that there is still an open [issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1976) related to internal host dns resolution in windows containers